# How to update multiple records in mysql with multiple ids

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html form which has 2*12 input fields with name="links[]" and name="ids[]"...
I want to update column 'link' with those 12 links using those 12 ids
I know we need a loop for that.
But don't know how to make the sql query.

```
$ids=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ids']);
    foreach($ids as $id){....}
$links=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['links']);
    foreach($links as $link){....}

$sql="update query.....";
```

EDIT:

It works with two variables $id and $season but when i add more than two variable like $episode etc. it doesn't work. it doesn't execute other variable only first two are executed and it sets the values of $season to 1 or sometimes 0 of all the entries in the table.

```
for($i=0 ; $i<count($record['id']); $i++){
  $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['id'][$i]);
  $season=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['season'][$i]);
  $episode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['episode'][$i]);
  $rel_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['rel_id'][$i]);
  $link=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['link'][$i]);

  //sQl Query
  $sql = "UPDATE series SET season='$season' and episode='$episode' and rel_id='$rel_id' and link='$link' WHERE id='$id'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {} 
        else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; };
```

Comment: Please ignore the suggestion above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
<form name="rec" id="rec" method="post">
<input type="text" name="reord[id][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[season][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[episode][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[rel_id][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[link][]">
<br/>

<input type="text" name="reord[id][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[season][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[episode][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[rel_id][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[link][]">

<br/>


<input type="text" name="reord[id][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[season][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[episode][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[rel_id][]">
<input type="text" name="reord[link][]">

</br>

<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $record = $_POST['reord'];
    $id = $season = $episode = $rel_id = $link = '';
    for($i=0 ; $i<count($record['id']); $i++){
         $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['id'][$i]);
         $season=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['season'][$i]);
         $episode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['episode'][$i]);
         $rel_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['rel_id'][$i]);
         $link= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $record['link'][$i]);
         echo $sql = "UPDATE series SET season='$season' and episode='$episode' and rel_id='$rel_id' and link='$link' WHERE id=$id";
        $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why it doesn't work with more than 2 variables? like when I add more variables after $links it sets all the values of $links to 1 and doesn't execute the other variables...

Comment: Can you please edit your code and add the latest. I will see

Comment: Shivendra singh... Done.

Comment: I checked it's working for any variable. I update the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Is it possible to add your form code, will check. because It's working for all the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys... but it's working now... it was a stupid mistake with the sql query I used and instead of "," commas... It's working after correcting the sql query... thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ids']);
    foreach($ids as $key => $id){
        $sql="update tablename set fieldname=value where link=$_POST[links][$key] and id=$id";
    }
```

This might work. If not give me more details.

Comment: Actually, no... I want to set feildname=$link(s) where id=$id(s)... both $links and $ids are more than 1 so we need loop for that...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `fieldname` = CASE
    WHEN id = 1 AND xyz = 3 THEN `value 1`
    WHEN id = 2 AND xyz = 3 THEN `value 2`
    WHEN id = 3 AND xyz = 3 THEN `value 3`
    END
```

In the scenario described I would use SET-WHEN-THEN query